# How to run multiple times a Docker container with different parameters in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gnu-parallel

I have a Docker container that reads a variable which I provide to it during the execution. Then I though that I would like to run many of those and pass a different value as variable for each one of those. Then, I just created a simple text file which contains all the values I want to pass into (they are about 20k different ones) and I am using `gnu-parallel` to spawn multiple Dockers in parallel.

My question is how I could do something like that in a Kubernetes environment?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the real problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want you want to do can be achieved using [kubernetes jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#what-is-a-job).
I would advise against using gnu parallel on kubernetes unless you can fit all the jobs in one node. If this is the case I think it's ok, just set the cpu request in the job template.